# Django export function and Celery task

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I would like to use Celery in order to run asynchronously my task and I'm getting some troubles with that. I would like to create a data file through export method.

**Context :**

User can export search result into a .xlsx file. 
However there are 2 cases :

- Search contains less than 70.000 rows. In this way, user can directly
  download the generated output file with `HttpResponse`.
- Search contains more than 70.000 rows. In this case, the file is
  written in the media folder thanks to a Celery task. By this way, even if the file is available few minutes after the request, user can navigate through the application. He will receive an email containing the link to download his generated file.

I'm working on this second part and I'm getting issues to set the Celery task.

**My code :**

This is the button used to execute the Celery task in my **HTML template** :

```
{% if item_count > 70000 %}
    {% if search_info_str %}
      <a title="Print" href="{% url print_link model='finalproduct' search_info=search_info_str %}" class="button btn btn-default print_items"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a>
      <a title="Export to Excel" name="export" class="button btn btn-default" href="{% url 'ocabr:cron_export' model=model search_info=search_info_str %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span></a>
    {% else %}
      <a title="Print" href="{% url print_link model='finalproduct' %}" class="button btn btn-default print_items"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a>
      <a title="Export to Excel" name="export" class="button btn btn-default" href="{% url 'ocabr:cron_export' model=model %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span></a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

This button calls my function thanks to this **urls.py** file :

```
app_name = 'ocabr'

urlpatterns = [

    # URL for the previous HTML template
    url(r'^finalproduct/list/$', FinalProductListView.as_view(), name='finalproduct-list'),

    # URL which calls Celery function
    url(r'^cron_export/(?P<model>[-\w]+)/(?P<search_info>.*)/$', CronExport.as_view(), name='cron_export'),
    url(r'^cron_export/(?P<model>[-\w]+)/$', CronExport.as_view(), name='cron_export'),

]
```

Then, I define inside a **cron.py** file this class :

```
class CronExport(View):

    def export_xls_celery(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        get_xls_export.delay(**kwargs)
        result = ['success_message', _('You will receive email in few minutes with result of data correction')]
        return render(request, 'ocabr/final_product/final_product_search.html', {result[0]: result[1]})

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.export_xls_celery(self.request)
        return render(request, 'ocabr/final_product/final_product_search.html')
```

The function `get_xls_export()` calls the **tasks.py** file which contains the export function :

```
@shared_task(bind=True, time_limit=3600, soft_time_limit=3600)
def get_xls_export(self, model="", search_info=""):
    app_label = 'ocabr'
    its_fp_or_up_product = False
    obsolete = False
    if self.GET.get('obsolete', '') == 'True':
        obsolete = True

    # some code with columns adjust, ..

    book.close()
    output.seek(0)
    name = 'Obsolete' if obsolete else ''
    name += str(model._meta.verbose_name_plural)

    name = name + "_" + str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%s")) + '.xlsx'
    default_storage.save(name, output)

    # Send mail to django admin
    receiver = settings.CRON_RECEIVER_MESSAGE
    message = "Hello, \n \n" \
              "This is an automatically generated e-mail. \n \n " \
              "On " + str(
        datetime.now()) + " with export file " + name + " available there : " + settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "/" + name

    try:
        send_mail(
            '[TEST database] Export file generated by OCABR',
            message, 'noreply@test.fr',
            receiver)
    except ConnectionRefusedError as e:
        return ['error_message', _('Error for sending email')]
    return ['success_message', _('Generation of export file is done')]
```

**Issue(s) :**

This is what I get when I click on my export button :

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /cron_export/finalproduct/
Exception Value: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I'm a bit lost and I don't overcome to launch my celery task

**EDIT :**

This is my final_product_search.html file :

```
{% extends 'list_crud/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load is_date %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>{% trans title %}</h2>

  {# Add record function #}
  {% if create_link %}
    <a class="button btn btn-default" href="{% url create_link %}" title="{% trans 'Add a Final Product to database' %}">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
  {% endif %}
  {% if item_count > 0 and item_count < 70000 %}
    {% if search_info_str %}
      <a title="Print" href="{% url print_link model='finalproduct' search_info=search_info_str %}" class="button btn btn-default print_items"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a>
      <a title="Export to Excel" class="button btn btn-default" href="{% url 'ocabr:export-xls' model=model search_info=search_info_str %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span></a>
    {% else %}
      <a title="Print" href="{% url print_link model='finalproduct' %}" class="button btn btn-default print_items"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a>
      <a title="Export to Excel" class="button btn btn-default" href="{% url 'ocabr:export-xls' model=model %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span></a>
    {% endif %}
  {% else %}
    {% if search_info_str %}
      <a title="Print" href="{% url print_link model='finalproduct' search_info=search_info_str %}" class="button btn btn-default print_items"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a>
      <a title="Export to Excel" name="export" value="export" class="button btn btn-default" href="{% url 'ocabr:cron_export' model=model search_info=search_info_str %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span></a>
    {% else %}
      <a title="Print" href="{% url print_link model='finalproduct' %}" class="button btn btn-default print_items"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a>
      <a title="Export to Excel" name="export" value="export" class="button btn btn-default" href="{% url 'ocabr:cron_export' model=model %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span></a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}

  {% if create_link or export_links %}<br><br>{% endif %}

  {# Search form #}
  <form id="form_search" class="navbar-search" method="GET" action="{{ url }}">

    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ search_form.mah|as_crispy_field}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ search_form.releasing_body|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ search_form.trade_name|as_crispy_field}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ search_form.member_state|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ search_form.pheur_name|as_crispy_field}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ search_form.decision|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ search_form.final_bulk_num|as_crispy_field}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ search_form.domain|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ search_form.manufacturer_name|as_crispy_field}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ search_form.date_from|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ search_form.name|as_crispy_field}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ search_form.date_to|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ search_form.eu_cert_n|as_crispy_field}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ search_form.status|as_crispy_field }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        {{ search_form.upstream_code_product|as_crispy_field}}
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-5">
        <label for="id_certificate_nullified" class="control-label ">
                Certificate nullified
        </label>
        {{ search_form.certificate_nullified }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="{% trans 'Search' %}" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="clear" value="Reset" onclick="clearForm(this.form);">

  </form>

  <br><br>

  {% if query_string %}
    <p class="text-info">Search results for <strong>{{ query_string }}</strong></p>
  {% endif %}

  {% block filter_bar %}
  {% endblock %}
  {# List of results #}
  {% if object_list %}
    {% with total=item_count %}
      {{ total }} record{{ total|pluralize }} / {{ total_records }}
    {% endwith %}
    {% block list_table %}
      <table id="table_{{ model }}" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table_model" style="table-layout:fixed; word-wrap: break-word;">
        {#    Headers #}
        <thead>
        <tr>
          {% for item in fields %}
            <th id="head_{{ item }}">
              {% if sort_by == item %}
                {% if order == 'asc' %}
                  <a href="?{% url_replace request 'sorting' '~'|add:item %}">
                    {{ labels|get_key:item }} </a>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up align-right pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                {% else %}
                  <a href="?{% url_replace request 'sorting' item %}">
                    {{ labels|get_key:item }} </a>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down align-right pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                {% endif %}
              {% else %}
                <a href="?{% url_replace request 'sorting' item %}">
                  {{ labels|get_key:item }}
                </a>
              {% endif %}
            </th>
          {% endfor %}
          {% block extra_field_header %}{% endblock %}
          {% if update_link or delete_link or view_link %}
              <th class="action_list"></th>
          {% endif %}
        </tr>
        </thead>
        {#    Rows #}
        <tbody>
        {% for item in object_list %}
          <tr id="tr_{{ item.pk }}">
            {% block default_values %}
              {% with values=item|get_ordered_values:fields %}
                {% for value in values %}
                  <td>
                    {% if value is not none %}
                      {{ value }}
                    {% endif %}
                  </td>
                {% endfor %}
              {% endwith %}
            {% endblock %}
            {% block extra_field_body %}{% endblock %}

            {% block actions %}
              {% if update_link or delete_link or view_link %}
                <td>
                  {% if view_link %}
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="{% url view_link pk=item.pk %}" title="View">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
                    </a>
                  {% endif %}
                  {% if update_link %}
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="{% url update_link pk=item.pk %}" title="Edit">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                    </a>
                  {% endif %}
                  {% if delete_link %}
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="{% url delete_link pk=item.pk %}" title="Delete">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    </a>
                  {% endif %}
                </td>
              {% endif %}
            {% endblock %}
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    {% endblock %}
  {% else %}
    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">{% trans "Nothing found" %}</div>
  {% endif %}

  {# Pagination #}
  {% include 'list_crud/pagination.html' %}

  {% block extra_html %}
  {% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

I'm also getting a Celery issue :

```
[2019-02-13 16:15:48,085: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task ocabr.tasks.get_xls_export[85cb15ea-1443-4ce6-8832-ce5e8a14a4ca] raised unexpected: AttributeError("'Context' object has no attribute 'GET'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/ocabr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 382, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/ocabr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 641, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/Bureau/Projets/ocabr/src/ocabr/tasks.py", line 26, in get_xls_export
    if self.GET.get('obsolete', '') == 'True':
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'GET'
```

Comment: Can you show the template 'final_product_search.html'? Also, it seems that your view `.get()` in the view does not call the `export_xls_celery`, so the celery task might not be delayed at all.

Comment: @mfrackowiak Oups sorry, I added the `export_xls_celery` call in my `.get()` function and the html file as you want. The issue remains the same.

Comment: And is the task delayed now? For me it seems that you lack the `print_link` in the context for the template rendering, and therefore it fails to reverse it in `{% url print_link ... %}`

Comment: I have an issue in Celery added in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the `kwargs` from the `get` handler to your export xlsx method:

```
def get(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.export_xls_celery(request, **kwargs)
```

Additionally, it seems that you want to access the request instance attributes in your task. Unfortunately, this is not possible - the best way to do this, would be to just pass the required ones as additional parameters. So, in the task:

```
@shared_task(bind=True, time_limit=3600, soft_time_limit=3600)
def get_xls_export(self, model="", search_info="", query_params=None):
    app_label = 'app'
    its_fp_or_up_product = False
    query_params = query_params or {}
    obsolete = False
    if query_params.get('obsolete', '') == 'True':
        obsolete = True
```

And in task call:

```
def export_xls_celery(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    get_xls_export.delay(query_params=request.GET, **kwargs)
    result = ['success_message', _('You will receive email in few minutes with result of data correction')]
    return render(request, 'app/final_product/final_product_search.html', {result[0]: result[1]})
```

Comment: Thank you with your answer, I updated my code and Celery returns : `TypeError: get_xls_export() got an unexpected keyword argument 'query_params'
`

Comment: Did you update the `get_xls_report` task definition with `query_params=None` as well?

Comment: Yes I did it as your example

Comment: Did you restart celery after making the changes?

Comment: I don't know why, but Celery seems to work (process loaded) but I still get this issue : `Reverse for 'cron_export' with keyword arguments '{'model': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['cron_export/(?P<model>[-\\w]+)/$', 'cron_export/(?P<model>[-\\w]+)/(?P<search_info>.*)/$']`

Comment: Where does it raise? You could probably change the `model` regex in your url pattern to `(?P<model>[-\w]*)`, or (even better) create a separate path that does not require the model param at all and use it in such case.