# How to efficiently export large Excel file with python and Django

Tags: python, django, excel

I have a really large database (billions of rows) that a user can query through a website build with django. I would like to offer the possibility for the user to download the results of their query in excel format. Currently the code is like:

```
from excel_response import ExcelResponse

qs = data.objects_in(db)
qs_results = qs.filter([...]).order_by([...]])

json_data = [['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]
    
    for item in qs_results:
    
    json_data.append([
        escape(item.col1),
        escape(item.col2),
        escape(item.col3),
    ])

    return ExcelResponse(json_data, 'title')
```

But this is really slow. The output can sometime have 100,000s of lines (and 20 columns) and take more than 10 minutes to be generated and often times out.

How can I output an excel file with a high number of row efficiently?

Comment: If all you need is `col1`, `col2` and `col3` from each object, using `.values_list()` will be vastly faster.

Answer (score 2):

you can follow this link to do the process using celery tasks
[Django export function and Celery task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54672644/django-export-function-and-celery-task)

or you can follow this link to do it using async view in django
https://thoslin.github.io/async-download-with-celery/

both are working great in those situations